# CSS for Contact-Form 7 Plugin, not getting picked equaly across the whole website

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming

I´ve Tweaked CSS for a contact 7 form and im showing that contact 7 through a Modal window.

In one page (homepage) the Modal window picks up the correct CSS for that Contact 7 form. Everything looks as i want it to be.

But On the other remaining pages, the Modal window picks up the same Contact 7 form **BUT without the same CSS.**

**Sample url where everything is OK:** 
[https://whitesaxevents.com/](https://whitesaxevents.com)  (*click on the Right corner "Floating Slider" and it will popup a Contact form with CSS as i wanted it to be*)

**The Other 2 Pages where the CSS is not applied:**
https://whitesaxevents.com/artistas/  and https://whitesaxevents.com/parcerias/

On these two URLS the CSS is different than the previous one, but im Calling exactly the same contact 7 form "short code".

**Any hints?**

Ive placed !important on the CSS elements i want to override, but i still continue to have a different styling on the contact form, dependant on the URL i call the modal. ALL these CSS tweaks have been done using the Default Custom CSS on Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ids don't match so this css selector won't work (div#wpcf7-f81862-o2.wpcf7)

id="wpcf7-f81862-o1" <- Not styled

id="wpcf7-f81862-o2" <- Styled

Comment: I cloned the CSS for the id wpcf7-f81862-01 and it worked! Thanks again!